# Printing SQLite database data on Graph

Tags: java, android, graph

I have two activities, first one asks user to input data in EditText and then user presses on button and that value is saved in SQLite database and showed in second's activites TextView.

Besides showing it in TextView I also want it to be displayed in Graph as a point, but have no idea how to do it. Points in graph are Float and when i try to convert TextView result in float it just wont work.

Anyway, here's the code of java file (second activity):

```
public class StatistikaGrafoviMain extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText buckysInput;
    TextView buckysText;
    StatistikeInputTezinaHelper dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistika_grafovi_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        buckysInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buckysInput);
        buckysText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buckysText);
        dbHandler = new StatistikeInputTezinaHelper(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();

        ValueLineChart mCubicValueLineChart = (ValueLineChart) findViewById(R.id.cubiclinechart);

        ValueLineSeries series = new ValueLineSeries();
        series.setColor(0xFF56B7F1);

// HERE ARE THE POINTS - THESE ARE JUST DEFAULT ONES, DON'T MIND THEM
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Jan", 2.4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Feb", 3.4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Mar", .4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Apr", 1.2f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Mai", 2.6f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Jun", 1.0f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Jul", 3.5f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Aug", 2.4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Sep", 2.4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Oct", 3.4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Nov", .4f));
        series.addPoint(new ValueLinePoint("Dec", 1.3f));

        mCubicValueLineChart.addSeries(series);
        mCubicValueLineChart.startAnimation();

    }
    //Add a product to the database
    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Product product = new Product(buckysInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addProduct(product);
        printDatabase();
    }

    //Delete items
    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String inputText = buckysInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteProduct(inputText);
        printDatabase();
    }

    //Print the database
    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        buckysText.setText(dbString);
        buckysInput.setText("");
    }

}
```

If you need me to post some extra code just write below.

Thanks!

EDIT

```
 public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Move to the first row in your results
        c.moveToFirst();

        //Position after the last row means the end of the results
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

Comment: So what is not working? Is your code throwing an `Exception`, is the value incorrect, different than what you were expecting? Or is it that you aren't sure how to go about retrieving the value?

Comment: I just don't know how to retrieve the value from database on a graph

Comment: Anybody knows solution?

Comment: Paste your  dbHandler.databaseToString() method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to draw lines from one point to others point,u can extends textview or imageview,then Override onDraw(Canvas canvas),canvas.drawLine(),u can solve the problem

Comment: Yes, that can draw lines, but how to draw lines with values from database?

Comment: u can read values from database,new a point class,the point class have some values what u need to draw line.i think it is simple,read values from database,drawline so simple.

Comment: Would you be so kind and show it on code in my first post?