# Spinner SharedPreferences returning 0/1 instead of Text

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-sharedpreferences

So I have a Spinner which sets value to another's activity TextView with Shared Preferences.

The whole process is working, but instead of saving text from the spinner items, it saves item position (Spinner has 2 possible values so it saves either 0 or 1).

Here's the code of Spinner

```
cilj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                settings.edit().putInt("PREF_SPINNER", position).commit();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        vrijednostSpinneraCilj = cilj.getSelectedItem().toString();

spremiRezultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppLayoutMain.class);
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 cilj.setSelection(settings.getInt("PREF_SPINNER", 0));
                editor.commit();
```

And second activity

```
 ciljTreningRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultatCilj);
        ciljTreningRezultat.setText(Integer.toString(settings.getInt("PREF_SPINNER", 0)));
```

I feel like I didn't made big mistake. Can anyone solve this??

EDIT

```
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ciljSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_cilj, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ciljSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cilj.setAdapter(ciljSpinnerAdapter);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppLayoutMain.class);

        cilj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                settings.edit().putString("PREF_SPINNER", cilj.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()).commit();

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        vrijednostSpinneraCilj = cilj.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

EDIT 2

```
  ciljTreningRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultatCilj);
        ciljSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_cilj, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        String selectedText = settings.getString("PREF_SPINNER", null);
        if(selectedText != null){
            cilj.setSelection(ciljSpinnerAdapter.getPosition(selectedText));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the selected text into preferences instead you are saving the position of the selected item. You need to save the selected text like this -

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                settings.edit().putString("PREF_SPINNER", cilj.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()).commit();
        }
```

And to fetch -

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String selectedText = settings.getString("PREF_SPINNER", null);
if(selectedText != null){
//Get the index of the selectedText from your spinner adapter array and set that position here

cilj.setSelection(ciljSpinnerAdapter.getPosition(selectedText));
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String error at that second line of fetching

Comment: What exactly should I type after if(selectedText != null){ ? I don't get it

Comment: Paste the code where you are setting the spinner adapter.

Comment: It's in the first post

Comment: You need to declare ciljSpinnerAdapter outside any method and then initialize it inside any method  -  ciljSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_cilj, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); Then you will have access to ciljSpinnerAdapter anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out second after I posted comment. Now it can't resolve 'getPosition'

Comment: cannot resolve method 'getPosition(java.lang.String)'

Comment: I don't why you are getting this issue because ArrayAdapter has getPosition() method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getPosition(T)

Comment: Don't know, is there any other way to solve it? Also, can you take a look in one of my other questions?  You seem like a smart guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929212/printing-sqlite-database-data-on-graph