# Custom Dialog onClickListener

Tags: java, android, dialog

So I have a custom Dialog that opens when user clicks on CardView. When the dialog is opened it lets the user to select one option and then opens a new activity.

The problem is, I can't set onClickListener to Dialog, and when I try to set onClickListener to TableRow (Dialog is from custom layout that has TableRows) I get NullPointerException on line `dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Here's my code:

```
karticaMainScreenOpcenitoGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AppLayoutMain.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.content_home_screen_opcenito_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_tumacenje_programa_naslov));
                dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve);
                dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(AppLayoutMain.this, StatistikeInputMain.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }

        });
```

Any solution?

Comment: R.id.dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve is in your dialog layout not in your activity layout, that's why you get a null pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference, having the null value.

I assume you missing to set `dialog`

```
 dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve = (TableRow)dialog. findViewById(R.id.dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve);
```

Comment: Remeber that `TableRow` should be initialize after the `show` method due the the fact that view is still not inflated at that time.

Comment: Thank you! Can you take a minute and look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929212/printing-sqlite-database-data-on-graph

Answer (score 2):

The problem:

`findViewById(R.id.dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve);`

You are referencing it in your activity layout therefore it will give you NPE.

You need to get the dialog instance and use its findViewById method after the `show` method of the dialog.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AppLayoutMain.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.content_home_screen_opcenito_dialog);
                dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_tumacenje_programa_naslov));
                dialog.show();

dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve = (TableRow) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve);
                    dialogHomeScreenOpcenitoUrediSve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(AppLayoutMain.this, StatistikeInputMain.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you take a minute and look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929212/printing-sqlite-database-data-on-graph